# How do I conditionally throw an exception in a concise way?

Tags: php, exception, syntax, throw

I need to throw an exception if a statement returns false and am trying to come up with a simple, concise way to do it. Any ideas? I wanted to do the following...

```
<?
  // ...
  oci_execute( $stmt ) or throw new OracleException( $stmt );
  // ...
?>
```

... but the PHP interpreter won't let me do it (syntax error) because 'throw' is a language construct.

Any ideas? I would like a very short one liner (no if statements please)

Comment: Very old question, but as of PHP 8.0 this is a valid statement.

RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/throw_expression

Answer (score 3):

```
<?
  // ...
  if (!oci_execute( $stmt )) throw new OracleException( $stmt );
  // ...
?>
```

is everything that comes my mind. But I've used PHP for not too long. Now I've discovered Perl which is a great thing and you can use the construct you suggest and many more. Always worth a try!

Comment: (P.S. I love perl and wish I could write this in perl, but can't)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. However, I have never actually had that particular need that you're describing, which leads me to suspect that you are doing something a bit strange. Or at least un-idiomatic. The presence of a procedural function (`oci_execute`) seems to support that.

I don't have any experience with Oracle from php, but could you use the [pdo-bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php) instead? That will give you a more object oriented interface to work with.

Comment: I would like to use PDO but it's Oracle support is highly experimental. I just want to use exceptions instead of having to check for a false return value when an error occurs. (oci functions return false if there's an error instead of telling you there's an error)

Comment: In that case, perhaps you can create a wrapper class that hides the procedural interface and does the throwing?

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
if !oci_execute($stmt) { throw new OracleException($stmt); }
```

work?